# Generate a password by ordinal python?

Tags: python

I want to generate a list like this: `["aaa","aab","aac",...]`. And I want to generate one string in one command like this: `nextpassword("aac")` not generate all lists in one time.

Comment: Is the value passed to `nextpassword` the last item of the list?

Comment: this is a idea from me, but you can use another way

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way. At first, you have to generate a list of password using your conditions. Then, you can choose randomly or sequentially.

```
import string
import random

# generation of password list using list comprehension
password_list = ['aa'+x  for x in string.ascii_lowercase]
# print(password_list)


# choose a random password
print(random.choice(password_list))
```

Comment: this will still generate the whole list in `password_list`

Answer (score 0):

This should work with any alphabet and offset, I'm using the spectacular [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/) package.

```py
import more_itertools
def next_string(current, offset=1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    alphabet_for_product = [alphabet] * len(current)
    current_index = more_itertools.product_index(current, *alphabet_for_product)
    result = more_itertools.nth_product(current_index + offset, *alphabet_for_product)
    return ''.join(result)

assert next_string('aac') == 'aad'
```